# sqlite with full text search doesn't find results when space in query

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I'm playing with [notmuch-abook](https://github.com/guyzmo/notmuch-abook) which uses sqlite3 to store names and email addresses.  The sqlite table uses full text search, being created by:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE AddressBook USING fts4(Name, Address);
```

I have entries for myself with names "Hamish", "Hamish D" and "Hamish Downer".  The query

```
select * from addressbook where addressbook match 'hamish';
```

Finds them all.  However

```
select * from addressbook where addressbook match 'hamish d';
```

Finds *only* the entries with the exact name "Hamish D" but *does not* find the entries with name "Hamish Downer".  I can get what I expect with:

```
select * from addressbook where name like 'hamish d%';
```

But I'd like to use the match version to match across both columns.  Any idea what's going on here?  Or how to get match to work as I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

The query

```
... addressbook match 'hamish d'
```

finds records that containt the two words `hamish` and `d`. You probably want to search for the phrase `hamish d` instead, which you can do with

```
... addressbook match '"hamish d"'
```

To search for prefixes, use `*`:

```
... addressbook match '"hamish d*"'
```

Comment: Thank you - I got a little lost in that long page of documentation.