# SQLite returns count equal to 0

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, full-text-search

I use `SQLite` to return a count of records that match a condition. The problem is I get the count equal to 0 (I thought something is wrong in my query, but I have just copied <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> to some SQLite GUI manager and it returns 10 - a good value...).

The code I use is:

```
_command = _sqlite.CreateCommand();
_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
_command.CommandText = query;
Int32 recordsFound = (Int32) _command.ExecuteScalar(); // 0 here, should be 10
```

My query that is being used:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE address MATCH '4 AND church'
```

Why does it work fine in GUI, but not with my code?:/

**[edit]**

But what's strange. If I use below query the result should be 2044 and it is 2044... wtf?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE address MATCH '4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answer here :

[sqlite with full text search doesn't find results when space in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137070/sqlite-with-full-text-search-doesnt-find-results-when-space-in-query)

you will have to escape the spaces in your query using "".
As it is, 'match' is looking for 4 as a whole word.

Comment: Hmmm, but what if I have some addresses which contains 10 words and I want to match only 2 tokens (not directly by each other).

Comment: I mean that I have an address 'lincoln road 32 blah blah london'. So the query '"32 lincoln"' matches nothing, but '32 AND lincoln' matches that address

Comment: searching for '32 lincoln' has an implicit AND

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say that I use `FTS4`. But now I have an idea, maybe the problem lies in my compilation of `System.Data.SQLite` that should be compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS` flag to enable extended `FTS` options like `AND/OR/NOT` in queries...